# save csv file as excel files using shell

Tags: excel, bash, shell, csv, cmd

is there anyway to save csv file as an excel files using shell scripts/command prompt?

I know that I can do it manually via the save as in the excel gui, but how do I make it an automated process?

Thanks!

Comment: mv {file}.csv {file}.xls
?

Comment: do you mean a script to convert all of your .csv to .xls?

Comment: You can use vbscript to do this.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198703

Comment: mv xx.csv yy.xls doesn't convert csv properly i think

Answer (score 4):

[csv2odf](http://csv2odf.sourceforge.net):

```
csv2odf data.csv template.xlsx output.xlsx
```

Comment: this works on both windows and linux, and tiny enough compared to the huge dependencies of ssconvert/gnumeric. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind doing it from within Excel, you can probably do something with VBA which will process multiple files at the same time.

Rather like: http://www.go4expert.com/forums/convert-xls-csv-using-vbscript-t18188/ but changing the saveas type.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=635437
You can use Perl Modules to parse and write Excel spread sheets.

You will need:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel
and
https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV::Simple

or

```
sudo apt-get install libspreadsheet-writeexcel-perl libtext-csv-perl
```

Then that script should work for you -